# Como enviar um objeto a um webservice Asp.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-service

Preciso enviar um objeto de uma classe que criei a um webservice, porém quando chamo o método passando o objeto ele da que os tipos são incompatíveis. Tentei receber o objeto como Object, porém da um erro ao gerar documento XML. Como posso enviar esse objeto?

Exemplo:
Usuário:

```
[Serializable]
public class Usuario 
{ 
   String _Nome; 

   public String Nome { 
      get { return _Nome;} 
      set { _Nome = value; } 
   } 
}
```

Um método que passa um objeto ao meu webservice da seguinte forma:

```
{
... 
WS.InformarNome(usuario); 
}
```

E o webservice recebe o usuario:

```
public void InformarNome(Usuario u) { ... }
```

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar um exemplo em código do que foi feito?

Comment: Possuo uma classe Usuário:
    [Serializable]
    public class Usuario
    {
     String _Nome;
     public String Nome
     {
      get { return _Nome;}
      set { _Nome = value; }
     }
    }    
    
Um método que passa um objeto ao meu webservice da seguinte forma:
     ...
     WS.InformarNome(usuario);
    
E o webservice recebe o usuario:
     ...
     public void InformarNome(Usuario u)
     {
     ...
     }

Comment: O melhor é você editar sua pergunta e colocar o código, fica mais legível. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/45143/edit

Comment: Editada, valeu!

Comment: Seguindo o código que você postou não aconteceu erro nenhum comigo. O usuário que você está mandando no `ws.InformarNome(usuario)` é um objeto do tipo Usuário ou um object?

Comment: Tipo Usuário mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize Json, deixe o método recebendo uma string que no caso será o objeto e então ao receber este objeto serializado, apenas utilize a api própria do .net para converter para o objeto.

```
public string Cadastro(string json)
        {
            Aluno aluno= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Aluno>(aluno);
        }
```